# Oracle PL/SQL code return null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I write this function in oracle PL/SQL to return counter of employee in the university based on their sex and collage nationality,sex , grade and qualification ETC.

```
FUNCTION GET_EMP_COUNT_GENERIC (
   P_ORGANIZATION_ID         VARCHAR2,
   P_GRADE                   VARCHAR2,
   P_SEX                     VARCHAR2,
   P_NAT_TYPE                VARCHAR2,
   P_DATE                    DATE,
   P_EMP_TYPE                VARCHAR2,
   P_QUALIFIC_CAT            VARCHAR2 )    
RETURN NUMBER IS 
   V_COUNT   NUMBER;
BEGIN
     SELECT   COUNT (EMP.PERSON_ID)  INTO   V_COUNT 
     FROM   PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F ASS,
            PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F EMP,
            HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS ORG,
            PAY_PEOPLE_GROUPS PPG,
            PER_GRADES GRD             
     WHERE  ASS.PERSON_ID = EMP.PERSON_ID
            AND ASS.ORGANIZATION_ID = ORG.ORGANIZATION_ID
            AND ASS.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID = PPG.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID
            AND ASS.GRADE_ID = GRD.GRADE_ID
            AND EMP.PERSON_TYPE_ID = 1145        
            AND (ASS.ORGANIZATION_ID = P_ORGANIZATION_ID OR P_ORGANIZATION_ID IS NULL)
            AND (GRD.NAME = P_GRADE                      OR P_GRADE IS NULL)
            AND (EMP.SEX = P_SEX                         OR P_SEX IS NULL)
            AND (PPG.SEGMENT2 = P_NAT_TYPE               OR P_NAT_TYPE IS NULL)
            AND (PPG.SEGMENT1 =P_EMP_TYPE                OR P_EMP_TYPE IS NULL)
            AND (XXPNU_HCM_PKG.GET_QUALIFICATION_NAME(EMP.PERSON_ID,EMP.BUSINESS_GROUP_ID) 
                              = P_QUALIFIC_CAT   OR P_QUALIFIC_CAT  IS NULL)
            AND P_DATE BETWEEN ASS.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
            AND  ASS.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
            AND P_DATE BETWEEN EMP.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
            AND  EMP.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE;                                 
   RETURN V_COUNT;    
END GET_EMP_COUNT_GENERIC;
```

But when I call it in query, its return null or zero value??
i dont know what is my mistake

```
        SELECT
XXPNU_HCM_PKG.GET_EMP_COUNT_GENERIC (null,null,'M',null,:P_DATE,'FACULTY',null) as FACULTY_M,
XXPNU_HCM_PKG.GET_EMP_COUNT_GENERIC (null,null,'F',null,:P_DATE,'FACULTY',null) as FACULTY_F
--------------------------------TABLES------------------------------------------

  FROM                PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F ASS,
                      PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F EMP,
                      HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS ORG,
                      PAY_PEOPLE_GROUPS PPG,
                      PER_GRADES GRD

--------------------------------- CONDITIONS -----------------------------------
  WHERE                 
                      ASS.PERSON_ID = EMP.PERSON_ID
                      AND ASS.ORGANIZATION_ID = ORG.ORGANIZATION_ID
                      AND ASS.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID = PPG.PEOPLE_GROUP_ID
                      AND ASS.GRADE_ID = GRD.GRADE_ID
                      AND EMP.PERSON_TYPE_ID = 1145

--------------------------------THIS YEAR DATE ---------------------------------

                     AND :P_DATE BETWEEN ASS.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                         AND  ASS.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
                     AND :P_DATE BETWEEN EMP.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                         AND  EMP.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE ;
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query inside the function on its own, manually passing the information across? That way, you can play around with the predicates and see what's causing the problem. For example, maybe there's a space on the values in the emp.sex column (e.g. 'M ' or 'F ') meaning when you query for 'M', no rows get returned because there are no 'M' values present. Without being able to work directly on your database, we can't say unless you provide a lot more information. Also, why are you selecting the function from your big query rather than `select your_function() from dual`?

Comment: " its return null or zero value" Those are two very different results. Which is it? Null would be quite surprising for an executed COUNT(). As you're running your function from a query you'd get an empty result set if the query returns no rows. Is that what's happening?

Comment: its return null not zero , also I find when I remove date parameters its retun values

Comment: how to select from dual please

Answer (score -1):

Your function will return 0 when it finds no rows that match your predicates in the function.

And because you use the function in the select-section of a select-statement it will return NULL when a exception occurs within the function.
Try using an exceptio handler returning -1. Then you know an exception occured.

remenber, an exception is not handled when a function is called within a select statement (in all DML I would say, but I don't know that for sure)

Comment: `And because you use the function in the select-section of a select-statement it will return NULL when a exception occurs within the function.` This isn't true - any raised by the function will cause the SELECT statement to throw an error, with the exception being the NO_DATA_FOUND error - it's perfectly valid for a SELECT statement to return no rows, so this error won't be reraised by the SELECT statement.